# No such file in this directory

Tags: xcode, directory

I am getting an error that says:

```
error: /Users/studentuse/Desktop/RSC/RSC/Default-568h@2x.png: No such file or directory
```

I have checked the folders and the file is there.  Not sure what to do.

Comment: Have you double checked the name of the file

Comment: have you checked capitalization? the double `RSC/` portion? do you have read permissions on the file ?

Comment: have you tried deleting derived data of project and restarting xcode?

Comment: how would I delete the derived data?  I have checked capitalization and there is a folder inside a folder and they are bot called RSC

Comment: Window -> Organizer -> Projects -> your project -> "Delete" button to the right of derived data folder path

Comment: All clicking on Organizer does is bring me to an issue navigator help page.

Comment: I also just realized that the file name is missing the -568h@ part.